# Angular 2 Ngrx Store: Updating Array

Tags: angular, typescript, ngrx, ngrx-store

I currently have an angular2 CRM app based on ngrx/store architecture.  I have the CRUD functions for updating, listing and adding customers working fine and all tied up to Firebase Database using ngrx/effects.

To keep the smart component in sync with the store i have the following code.  Again all working fine, however i am unsure about how to update an array in the form - see code below: -

This is where i update the form with the data from the store

```
if (this.customer) {

          this.customerForm.get('name').setValue(this.customer.name);
          this.customerForm.get('overview').setValue(this.customer.overview);
          this.customerForm.get('imagePath').setValue(this.customer.imagePath);

          console.log("ngOnChanges", this.customer);

        }
```

I want to do a similar thing with address form but unsure how to do the above to populate the array object in the form.  Any ideas / suggestions welcome

When i log the console below i actually have the address details just need to know how to get them into the form object.

```
Object
addresses: Array(2)
0:Object
1:Object
length:2
imagePath:"http://www.bytes.co.uk/application/themes/bytes/img/bytes-technology-group.svg"
name:"Bytes Technology Group Emirates LLC"
overview:"Kronos Re-Seller for the Middle East and GCC Countries and Egypt"
parentId:"-KcRRsAGRYASXNU3gO_F"
```

**Full Customer Detail Smart Component**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, Output, EventEmitter, ChangeDetectionStrategy, OnChanges } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, FormArray, Validators, FormControl } from "@angular/forms";

// Mojito Models
import { CustomerModel } from '../../models/customer-model';
import { AddressType } from '../../../shared/models/address.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'mj-customer-detail',
  templateUrl: './customer-detail.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./customer-detail.component.scss'],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class CustomerDetailComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {

  @Input() customer: CustomerModel;
  @Output() updatedCustomer: EventEmitter<CustomerModel> = new EventEmitter<CustomerModel>();
  @Output() showView: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter<string>();
  @Output() customerId: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter<string>();

  customerForm: FormGroup;
  addressForm: FormGroup;

  addressTypes: AddressType[] = [
    { "id": 1, "name": "Work" },
    { "id": 2, "name": "Home" },
  ]

  private newAddressGroup() {
    return new FormGroup({
      type: new FormControl,
      street: new FormControl,
      city: new FormControl,
      country: new FormControl,
      postalCode: new FormControl
    })
  }

  get addresses() {
    return (this.addressForm.get('addressGroups') as FormArray).controls;
  }


  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {

    this.customerForm = this.fb.group({
      name: [null, Validators.required],
      overview: [null, Validators.required],
      imagePath: [null, Validators.required],
    });

    this.addressForm = this.fb.group({
      addressGroups: this.fb.array([])
    });
  }

  ngOnChanges() {

    if (this.customer) {

      this.customerForm.get('name').setValue(this.customer.name);
      this.customerForm.get('overview').setValue(this.customer.overview);
      this.customerForm.get('imagePath').setValue(this.customer.imagePath);

      console.log("ngOnChanges", this.customer);

    }

  }

  ngOnInit() {



  }

  onAddAddressGroup() {
    const fa = this.addressForm.controls["addressGroups"] as FormArray;

    fa.push(this.newAddressGroup());

  }

  onSaveAddress() {
    const addresses = this.addressForm.controls["addressGroups"].value;
    this.customer.addresses = addresses;
    this.onSaveCustomer();
  }

  onSaveCustomer() {

    this.customer = Object.assign(this.customer, this.customerForm.value);
    this.updatedCustomer.emit(this.customer);
    this.showView.emit('list');

  }

  onDeleteCustomer() {

    this.customerId.emit(this.customer.$key);
    this.showView.emit('list');


  }

  goBack() {

    this.showView.emit('list');

  }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the values by iterating the data you have in `customer.addresses` and by the way, you can shorten the setting of values, instead of setting each value separate, you can make it shorter like:

```
ngOnChanges() {
  if (this.customer) {
    // set values in customerForm
    this.customerForm.setValue({
      name: this.customer.name,
      overview: this.customer.overview;
      imagePath: this.customer.imagePath
    })
    // set controls to addressForm, formArray
    let control = <FormArray>this.addressForm.get('addressGroups');
    this.customer.addresses.forEach(x => {
       control.push(this.fb.group({...}))
    })
  }
}
```

Notice the `this.fb.group({...})` I'm not sure what form controls you have there, so you need to append them... Something like:

```
this.fb.group({myFormControlName1: x.myProperty1, myFormControlName2: x.myProperty2....})
```

Comment: `I'm not sure what form controls you have there` He uses `newAddressGroup` :) So you can update answer

Comment: I understand he wants to set the values from the `customer.addresses`? Quote: ***When i log the console below i actually have the address details just need to know how to get them into the form object.**

Comment: Yes, i think you answered correctly. I just hinted that his address group looks like `new FormGroup({
      type: new FormControl,
      street: new FormControl,
      city: new FormControl,
      country: new FormControl,
      postalCode: new FormControl
    })`

Comment: @ccocker you are very welcome, glad I could help! :) Have a good one and happy coding!